# How does d[count]d, y[count]y like d3d, y3y work?

Tags: vim

I have known that `3dd` and `3yy` will repeat `dd` and `yy` 3 times respectively. But how does `d3d` and `y3y` work?

In the Vim manual, the command for deleting and yanking is `d{motion}` and `y{motion}`. And `{motion}` is "Left-right", "Up-down", "Word motions", etc. And the `d` and `y` are **operators**, not `{motion}`.

If I adhere to the rules above, then `d3y` will not work because `y` is not `{motion}` key.

So how does `d3d` work? I have googled for some material about it such as [How can I map d[count]d?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/how-can-i-map-dcountd), but there is no answer about it.
And is there Vim manual about it?

<sub>I commonly use `[count]dd` and `[count]yy` to delete lines. And I didn't know `d[count]d` and `y[count]y` work before today</sub>

Comment: `3dd` means "delete 1 line, repeat 3 times", while `d3d` means "delete 3 lines". It's the same end result, but not the same mechanism. You could do `3d3d`, for example to delete 9 lines, by deleting 3 lines at a time and repeating it 3 times...

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are technically verbs (operators), but in this case I think they are actually being substituted as nouns (objects). Imagine `d3w`. That means delete 3 words, with `d` being the verb, and `w` the noun. `d3d` is just being interpreted as delete three times, and defaults to 3 lines because another noun wasn't specified.

Comment: Your statement gets right to the point. But I can't find any reference about the usage. `d3d` usage pattern (that extends to `opertor[count]operator`) maybe special case in Vim.

Comment: @zhenguoli yeah, it might just be a special case. I looked at the vim manual and haven't found anything concrete.